# Possible authentication vulnerability, is it an issue?

Tags: authentication, vulnerability

I have found an interesting bug (?), but I'm not sure if it is an actual vulnerability.
Let's assume we have target, A, user, B, and 3rd party auth provider, C.
User B signs up with target A with their email. User B doesn't have an account with C. A few weeks later, User B decides to sign up with company C, and next time user B goes to log into A, they choose to sign in with C. They get in.
Basically, user B never linked C and A, but A let C in anyway.
Now the reason this isn't a vulnerability yet is because C requires email verification. But is it possible this is still a vulnerability? I have a feeling it is. How can I test for this?

P.S. I am an ethical hacker and this is a company request ethical hacking on HackerOne.

Comment: Not a vulnerability, but a bug. The ID token that (C)harles is giving to (A)lice contains the email ID of (B)ob. The ID token is trusted by Alice so she is letting Bob to sign in as ID token is the proof of authentication. But she should not allow Bob to sign-in without signing up first because user registration takes consent and agreement of the user before letting the user to use the service. Directly allowing signing in with SSO without signup is skipping the consent part.

Comment: This is similar to an account takeover bug with third-party Auth providers, which happens surprisingly often, due to the fact that to correctly setup auth systems is not that simple and there's a lot of room for error.